# Find a probability space of the coin tossing game

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> A fair coin is tossed as long as no one has won. Player $A$ wins if the sequence $(T,H,T)$ appears and player $B$ wins if $(H,H,H)$ appears. Define a probability space $ (\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ of the game!

---

We could simply define $\Omega:=2^{\mathbb{N}}$. But in this case it is not clear how to get well defined probability function nor a $\sigma$-algebra.

Let's choose some $\omega\in\Omega$. If we try the function

\begin{align*}
p(\omega):=\begin{cases}
2^{-n},&\text {if }\omega \text{ ends with } HHH\text{ or } THT\\
0 ,&\text {if }\omega \text{ doesn't end with } HHH\text{ or } THT\\
0 ,&\text {if }\omega \text{ is of infinte length},
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

then the problem is to show that $\sum\limits_{\omega\in\Omega}p(\omega)=1$. Is it possible at all to show this or should I use another sample space? And what about the $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: What do you mean by "ends with ..." if $\omega$ is a binary sequence?

Comment: @AlvinL, it means that the last three entries of $\omega$ attain the values $HHH$ or $THT$. E.g.  $\omega\in2^{\mathbb{N}}$ could attain a form like $\omega=(HHTHTHTH)$. In this case $p(HHTHTHTH)=0$ because the game stops after the $5$th round.

Comment: any $\omega$ is of the form $(a_k)_{k\in\mathbb N}$ where $a_k \in \{H,T\}$. These are sequences, they don't end. You can define a winning condition, sure.

Comment: @AlvinL, yes they are sequences, either finite or infinite, but how does this help?

Comment: They're all infinitely long sequences, not finite.

Comment: Remember that a probability measure actually measures *sets* of outcomes, not just individual outcomes. And your probability measure doesn't need to encode the win conditions of the game, it just needs to model the coin tossing. The win conditions are events.

Comment: Indeed, you shouldn't need to change the probability measure if you change the rules of the game. The events that occur should still be measured the same way.

Comment: Keep in mind that for the game to end at a given number $n$ of steps, it must be the case that neither pattern HHH or THT has occurred during the first $n-1$ coin tosses. [That may be more difficult to compute than simply having the last three tosses be either HHH or THT.] I agree with others that the sample space is all sequences of tosses, and that "A wins" and "B wins" are merely events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking $\ \Omega=\{H,T\}^\mathbb{N}\ $ as your sample space is certainly one way to start setting  up a mathematical model of the game. In fact this is typically the usual approach for modelling an indefinite number of tosses of a fair coin.  Doing this, however, does causes some difficulties, for the following reasons:

- A [*probability* space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) is a triple $\ (\Omega, \mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})\ $, where $\ \Omega\ $ is your sample space, $\ \mathscr{F}\ $ is a [$\ \sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra) of subsets of $\ \Omega\ $, and $\ \mathbb{P}:\mathscr{F}\rightarrow[0,1]\ $ is a [probability measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure) on $\ \mathscr{F}\ $. In addition to the sample space $\ \Omega\ $, you therefore also need to specify $\ \mathscr{F}\ $ and $\ \mathbb{P}\ $ to complete your description of the probability space.
- The set $\ \Omega\ $ is uncountable. As a consequence, it's not possible to take $\ \mathscr{F}\ $ to be the collection of *all*  subsets of $\ \Omega\ $, nor to use a [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) to define $\ \mathbb{P}\ $, as you appear to have been trying to do.  In fact, if $\ \omega\in\Omega\ $ and $\ \{w\}\in\mathscr{F}\ $, then you will have to take $\ \mathbb{P}\big(\{w\}
   \big)=0\ $ for every such $\ \omega\ $.
- There's nothing about the probability space  $\ (\Omega, \mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})\ $ by itself—as so far described—that distinguishes it as a representation of the game you've described. As suggested by the comments to your question, you would need to ensure that the events that $\ A\ $ wins the game and that $\ B\ $ wins the game both belong to $\ \mathscr{F}\ $.
- In this setting, the event $\ \mathcal{A}\ $ that $\ A\ $ wins is the
  *set* of sequences $\ \omega\in\Omega\ $ containing the subsequence $\ THT\ $ and in which any occurrence of the subsequence $\ HHH\ $ is
  later than the first occurrence of $\ THT\ $. The event $\
     \mathcal{B}\ $ that $\ B\ $ wins is a similarly defined subset of $\
     \Omega\ $.  If $\ \mathcal{A}\in\mathscr{F}\ $, $\
     \mathcal{B}\in\mathscr{F}\ $, and $\ \mathscr{F}\ $ is a properly
  defined $\ \sigma$-algebra, then the event $\
     \mathcal{N}=\Omega\setminus(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{B})\ $ that
  *neither* $\ A\ $ nor $\ B\ $ wins the game must also belong to $\ \mathscr{F}\ $. The event $\ \mathcal{N}\ $ is the set of sequences
  $\ \omega\in\Omega\ $ in which there are *no* occurrences of either
  of the subsequences $\ THT\ $ or  $\ HHH\ $.   All three of the
  events $\ \mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}\ $, and $\ \mathcal{N}\ $ are
  *uncountable* sets, which means it's impossible to specify their probabilities by using a probability mass function $\
     p:\Omega\rightarrow[0,1]\ $ for which $\
     \mathbb{P}(X)=\sum_\limits{\omega\in X}p(\omega)\ $.

There's a standard technique for dealing with all the above-mentioned difficulties, which you'll find described in any good modern treatise on the theory of probability—as on pp.$19$-$25$ of [Leo Breiman's classic text, *Probability*](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9781611971286) for instance.   Applying this technique, however, relies on some acquaintance with the measure-theoretical foundations of advanced probability, and if you've only ever studied elementary probability theory, these are unlikely to be among the tools currently available to you.  Also, since the game stops as soon as one of the sequences $\ THT\ $ or $\ HHH\ $ appears, it therefore seems somewhat unnatural to me to be using the sets $\ \mathcal{A}\ $ and  $\ \mathcal{B}\ $ of *infinitely long* sequences to represent the events that $\ A\ $ wins, or that $\ B\ $ wins, respectively, and to be going through the rigmarole of setting up the probability space $\ (\Omega, \mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})\ $ described above when there's another approach available that's both more elementary and more natural.

For each $\ n=3,4,\dots\ $, let $\ \mathcal{A}_n, \mathcal{B}_n\ $ be the sets of *finite* sequences *of length* $\ n\ $ that terminate in the subsequences $\ THT\ $ or $\ HHH\ $ respectively, and contain no other occurrences of either of those subsequences. Let
\begin{align} \mathcal{A}_\infty&=\bigcup_\limits{i=3}^\infty\mathcal{A}_n\\
\mathcal{B}_\infty&=\bigcup_\limits{i=3}^\infty\mathcal{B}_n\ ,\ \text{ and}\\
\Omega_\infty&=\mathcal{A}_\infty\cup\mathcal{B}_\infty\ .
\end{align}
The sets $\ \mathcal{A}_\infty\ $ and $\ \mathcal{B}_\infty\ $ seem to me to be much more natural representations of the events that $\ A\ $ wins or that $\ B\ $ wins than the sets $\ \mathcal{A}\ $ and $\ \mathcal{B}\ $, defined above, are. They are also only *countably* infinite, as is their union $\ \Omega_\infty\ $.  We therefore encounter no problems defining a candidate for a probability mass function $\ p:\Omega_\infty\rightarrow[0,1]\ $ by
$$
p(\omega)=\frac{1}{2^{|\omega|}}\ ,
$$
where $\ |\omega|\ $ is the length of the sequence $\ \omega\ $ (which is finite for all $\ \omega\in\Omega_\infty\ $), and defining the probability of $\ \mathbb{P}(E)\ $ of *any* subset $\ E\ $ of $\ \Omega_\infty\ $ to be given by
$$
\mathbb{P}(E)=\sum_{\omega\in E}\frac{1}{2^{|\omega|}}\ .
$$
The one fly in the ointment, if you're going to take $\ \Omega_\infty\ $ as your sample space, is that you'd have to show that $\ \mathbb{P}\big(\Omega_\infty\big)=\sum_\limits{\omega\in \Omega_\infty}\frac{1}{2^{|\omega|}}=1\ $.  While this is true, the proof requires a little work, and it turns out to be unnecessary.  It's much easier to show that $\ \sum_\limits{\omega\in \Omega_\infty}\frac{1}{2^{|\omega|}}\le1\ $, and you can allow for the possibility that the inequality might be strict by augmenting your putative sample space with an extra elementary outcome, $\ \omega_\infty\ $, say, to represent the possibility that the game never terminates, and setting $\ p\big(\omega_\infty\big)=1-\sum_\limits{\omega\in \Omega_\infty}\frac{1}{2^{|\omega|}}\ $.

Since $\ \mathcal{A}_3\cup\mathcal{B}_3, \mathcal{A}_4\cup\mathcal{B}_4, \dots,\mathcal{A}_n\cup\mathcal{B}_n,\dots\ $ are pairwise disjoint, and $\ \Omega_\infty=\bigcup_\limits{n=3}^\infty\big(\mathcal{A}_n\cup\mathcal{B}_n\big)\ $,then
\begin{align}
\sum_\limits{\omega\in \Omega_\infty}\frac{1}{2^{|\omega|}}&=\sum_{r=3}^\infty\sum_\limits{\omega\in\mathcal{A}_r\cup\mathcal{B}_r}\frac{1}{2^{|\omega|}}\\
&=\sum_{r=3}^\infty\frac{\big|\mathcal{A}_r\cup\mathcal{B}_r\big|}{2^r}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{r=3}^n2^{n-r}\big|\mathcal{A}_r\cup\mathcal{B}_r\big|\ ,
\end{align}
where $\ |X|\ $ is the cardinality of the set $\ X\ $.  Now $\ 2^{n-r}\big|\mathcal{A}_r\cup\mathcal{B}_r\big|\ $ is just the number of sequences of length $\ n\ $ which contain an occurrence of one of the subsequences $\ THT\ $ or $\ HHH\ $ for the first time at positions $\ r-2, r-1, r\ $, so $\ \sum_\limits{r=3}^n2^{n-r}\big|\mathcal{A}_r\cup\mathcal{B}_r\big|\ $ is the number of sequences of length $\ n\ $ which contain one of the subsequences $\ THT\ $ or $\ HHH\ $.  This must certainly be less than the total number of sequences of length $\ n\ $—namely, $\ 2^n\ $.  Therefore, $\ \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_\limits{r=3}^n2^{n-r}\big|\mathcal{A}_r\cup\mathcal{B}_r\big|<1\ $. Since the left side of this inequality is an increasing function of $\ n\ $ it must converge to a limit $\ L\le1\ $ as $\ n\rightarrow\infty\ $, and we have
$$
\sum_\limits{\omega\in \Omega_\infty}\frac{1}{2^{|\omega|}}=L\le1\ .
$$
Now let $\ \Omega_\infty^+=\Omega_\infty\cup\big\{\omega_\infty\big\}\ $ and extend $\ p\ $ to $\ \Omega_\infty^+\ $ by putting $\ p\big(\omega_\infty\big)=1-L\ $. We then have
\begin{align}
\sum_\limits{\omega\in \Omega_\infty^+}p(\omega)&=p\big(\omega_\infty\big)+\sum_\limits{\omega\in \Omega_\infty}\frac{1}{2^{|\omega|}}\\
&=1\ ,
\end{align}
so $\ p\ $ is a well-defined probability mass function on $\ \Omega_\infty^+\ $.  You can therefore take $\ \Omega_\infty^+\ $ to be your sample space, and its power set to be your $\ \sigma$-algebra of events.  Let $\ \mathscr{F}_\infty\ $ be the power set, and define the probability measure $\ \mathbb{P}\ $ on $\ \mathscr{F}_\infty\ $ by
$$
\mathbb{P}(E)=\sum_{\omega\in E}p(\omega)
$$
for $\ E\in\mathscr{F}_\infty\ $.  With these definitions, $\ \big(\Omega_\infty^+,\mathscr{F}_\infty,\mathbb{P}\big)\ $ is a probability space which you could take to be the probability space of the game.